# Ler um string de um Arquivo com espaco

Tags: c, arquivo

Olá, eu quero ler uma linha de arquivo e depois retorna o numero de espaços também, mas primeiro estou tentando retorna a string inteira porém quando eu insiro um espaço não é exibido o restante da string depois disso.

```
void LerArquivo()
{
FILE *fp;
char  string2[100];
int i=0,size;

   fp=fopen("PoxaProfessor.txt","r+");
   if(fp==NULL)
   {
       printf("Arquivo nao pode ser aberto");
   }


   fscanf(fp,"%s",string2);
   size=strlen(string2);
   printf("%s",string2);

   printf("\nNumeros de Caracteres: %d",size);
   printf("\nCincos Primeiros Caracteres: ");
   while(i<5)
   {
    printf("%c",string2[i]);
    i++;
   }

   fclose(fp);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está usando fscanf para a leitura e passando "%s" como parâmetro, o que isso quer dizer? Você está lendo uma palavra do arquivo passado em fscanf. Como solucionar isso? Usando funções para ler uma linha inteira, como: fgets (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) ou modificando seu parâmetro em scanf para "%[^\n]s" que significa "leia até encontrar um \n".

Seu código com a correção:

```
void LerArquivo()
{
FILE *fp;
char  string2[100];
int i=0,size;

   fp=fopen("PoxaProfessor.txt","r+");
   if(fp==NULL)
   {
       printf("Arquivo nao pode ser aberto");
   }


   fscanf(fp,"%[^\n]s",string2);
   size=strlen(string2);
   printf("%s",string2);

   printf("\nNumeros de Caracteres: %d",size);
   printf("\nCincos Primeiros Caracteres: ");
   while(i<5)
   {
    printf("%c",string2[i]);
    i++;
   }

   fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: se eu gravar uma string assim "xx dd rr" ,ele continua só retornando xx e ignorando o resto da string

Comment: Anexei seu código corrigido na minha resposta. Testei aqui e está funcionando com a entrada "xx dd rr" no arquivo.